# Elasticsearch Slow as size parameter increases (not dependent on data size)

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, search

I have the following peculiar case for a simple GET request `"query": {"match_all": {}},"sort": ["_doc"]` with:

1. size = 0:

   - _source = ["X"]: 0.03 sec and 262 bytes
   - _source = ["X", "Y", "Z"]: 0.02 sec and 262 bytes
2. size = 10:

   - _source = ["X"]: 0.90 sec and 2944 bytes
   - _source = ["X", "Y", "Z"]: 0.88 sec and 949 Kb
3. size = 20:

   - _source = ["X"]: 1.20 sec and 5613 bytes
   - _source = ["X", "Y", "Z"]: 1.14 sec and 1006 Kb
4. size = 60:

   - _source = ["X"]: 2.30 sec and 9693 bytes
   - _source = ["X", "Y", "Z"]: 2.08 sec and 1120 Kb

The fields "X", "Y", "Z" are of type "text" and hold either years, either one / two words.
Seems to me that the increase in `data size` is not the problem of the slow query, but rather only the increase in `size` parameter.

For 1120Kb of data, it shouldn't take 2.5 seconds to retrieve the data - way too much.

I have an architecture of one cluster with one node and 5 indices. Each index has 1 shard allocated except for an index which has 2 shards.
RAM capacity is of 58GB and the heap size is 8GB.
The Elasticsearch version is 7.6

I already have:

1. request cache set to True
2. cache size equal to 20% of heap
3. preload of ["nvd", "dvd", "dvm", "doc"]
4. no explicit refresh
5. refresh_time of 2s on the index on which the queries are done
6. 2 shards on on the index on which the queries are done
7. swap disabled

GET `_cat/indices` shows the heap is used 63% and the RAM is used 37% (it should be the other way around)

GET `index/_settings` shows the fetch phase is 76 times bigger than the query phase! (~2.3s vs 0.03s)

Where could the problem be?
Thanks in advance.